# Styling many to many field in form

Tags: django, forms

I created form based on this model:

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    miniature = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/playlist', default="defaults/default.png", validators=[validate_miniature_file_extension])
    tracks = models.ManyToManyField(Track)
```

form:

```
class AddPlaylist(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Playlist
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'tracks', 'miniature']
        widgets = {
            'description': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 30, 'rows': 10}),
        }
```

When I rendered it, behavior of "tracks" surprised me. It looks like this:

[image]

First thing: Names - I want to name those tracks with (Track is model and has field "title") Track.title. How can I do it? I didn't found anything when I was searching for widgets to ManyToManyField.

Second thing: Selecting - for example when I click on Track object(1) when Track object(4) is selected, obj(4) becomes unselected, and obj(1) becomes selected. Using shift provides to select fields between objects (between obj(1) and obj(3) for example), but user can't select obj(1) and obj(3) for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For naming the tracks you need to define `__str__()` on your Track model.

```
class Track(models.Model):
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

To select multiple non-consecutive options, use the command/control key instead of shift. Alternatively you can use the CheckboxSelectMultiple widget to display checkboxes.

```
from django import forms


class AddPlaylist(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Playlist
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'tracks', 'miniature']
        widgets = {
            'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 30, 'rows': 10}),
            'tracks': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. But I though about something that will let user do it with just click? Is it possible?

Comment: Sure, you can use CheckboxSelectMultiple to display checkboxes instead. I updated my answer.